# What happens when you assign a variable within a formula?

Tags: c++, variables, variable-assignment

Soo... this is bad practice and a nightmare to debug. But for the sake of curiosity:

What really happens when you assign a variable within a formula? And is there a performance deficit?

```
var xx, yy, zz;
xx = 45;
zz = xx * (yy = 45);
```

Comment: The value `45` is assigned to variable `yy`. The whole expression `(yy = 45)` has value `45` as well and will be used like any expression. The parentheses are important due to the precedence of assignment `=`.

Comment: @Scheff the value of the expression is `yy`  ,  later on (i.e. when processing operands of `*`) it will have its value looked up which retrieves 45

Comment: @M.M OK, correct: `(yy = 45)` returns the reference to `yy`. When it is used as expression it "decays" to its value `45`. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The `=` operator assigned the right hand value to he left hand variable and returns it. So, reading from withing the parenthesis outwards - `45` is assigned to `yy` and then returned. Next, `xx` (which is also `45`) is multiplied by `45`, resulting in `2025` which is assigned to `zz`.

Comment: Yeah, so I get that, but does anything weird happen at the assembly level or does it affect performance? Or is it just ugly?

Comment: The result of `=` is the left operand, `yy` here (not `45`)

Comment: @FatalSleep It's hard to say what happens at the assembly code level. C++ does not specify down that far. Partially because there are too many completely different CPUs that all have completely different assembly languages. You can use [a tool like godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/toP5br) to see what happens for some common compilers and a few common CPU architectures. You can see in the link that the exact same code is generated (and most of each function is thrown out as unnecessary) for both cases in this case.

Comment: At assemblee level, the difference with or without yy assignment should just be an additional instruction like `mov, yy, eax`. The value isn't cleared from the register, it's in fact a copy rather than a move.